# SQL query returning same row of data twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query returns the same row of data twice. Is there something wrong with my inner join? Or where clause?

```
 SELECT 
     transaction_details.transaction_number,
     transaction_details.transaction_id,
     transaction_details.product_id,
     Products3.ProductName
 FROM 
     transaction_details
 INNER JOIN 
     Products3 ON transaction_details.product_id = Products3.productID
 INNER JOIN 
     transaction_status ON transaction_details.transaction_id = transaction_status.transaction_id
 WHERE 
     transaction_details.transaction_id = 'tr-y9404'
     AND status_of_transaction = 'pending'
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: I suspect you have multiple `transaction_details` records for each `transaction`? Change to `select * from...` and see which column is changing, that will point you to the table that has multiple records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have multiple entries in your table? In that case you can use SELECT DISTINCT. This will remove duplicates.